# ASP.NET searchable dropdownlist server control with selectedindexchanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, custom-server-controls, servercontrols

I am creating an ASP.NET/VB.net web application. I'm looking for a (preferably FREE) searchable dropdownlist server control that I can easily incorporate into my various ASP.NET applications.

I have been searching online and found several solutions that are jQuery based, etc.... But, I haven't been able to find any server controls that support (ie extend) the standard dropdownlist events, properties, etc.... In particular the SelectedIndexChanged event. Do you have any recommendations? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=111) is a an example using the [ListExtenderControl](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/ListSearch/ListSearch.aspx). You will need to use the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit.